# Driver name for SQL Server in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect SQL Server with my Java application but I don't know the driver class name which is provided in  Class.forName(driverName);

I am using Eclipse, I have imported JAR file in my project and also added it to the Build path.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        String query = "CREATE TABLE student("
                + "id       INT     PRIMARY KEY,"
                + " name    VARCHAR(20)"
                + ");";

        try {
            Class.forName("WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE ?");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://lakshya:1433");
            System.out.println("Conenction established.");

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.executeQuery();

            System.out.println("student table created..");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot compile the code any further because I don't know the driver name.

Comment: Please link to the jar you're using?

Comment: @hd1 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55539 
I am using this JAR file

Comment: Please see my answer for help.

Answer (score 3):

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#making-a-simple-connection-to-a-database), the class name is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

However, with any JDBC driver produced since 2006 (for JDBC 4 or higher), you don't need to load the driver with `Class.forName` in an application like this. If the driver is on the initial class path, it will get loaded automatically.

Only in more complex class loading situations (eg web applications), you may need to load explicitly, but in those types of applications you would normally configure a `DataSource` instead of using `DriverManager`.

In short, you should be able to remove the line `Class.forName("WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE ?");` and your application will work, provided you have the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC jar on the class path when running the application.

Also make sure to consult the rest of the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), as your current JDBC url is incomplete as it doesn't contain a database name.

Answer (score 0):

The file you download -- either zip or tar.gz -- will contain a jar file. In it, you'll find a file named "META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver", which contains your driver class.

As noted by Mr Rotteveel, you probably don't need to specify the driver explicitly, though.